# dpkg: error processing package amavisd-new (--configure) when trying wordpress installation

Tags: software-installation, dpkg, wordpress

I am a new to Ubuntu and I just installed Ubuntu server 16.04
on my system , when I try to install wordpress it shows this error. What is this error and how can I solve this problem:

```
dpkg: error processing package amavisd-new (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 amavisd-new
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Comment: This has nothing to do with the wordpress installation. Whatever you try to install will return that error because amavisd did not finish to install.

What is the output of systemctl status amavis.service

Comment: Could you please [edit] your question to include the output of the terminal command `sudo apt-get install -f`? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The solution is to set your FQND (Fully Qualified Domain Name, e.g. mail.yourdomainname.com) in `/etc/amavis/conf.d/05-node_id`

It should look like this:

```
use strict;

# $myhostname is used by amavisd-new for node identification, and it is
# important to get it right (e.g. for ESMTP EHLO, loop detection, and so on).

chomp($myhostname = `hostname --fqdn`);

# To manually set $myhostname, edit the following line with the correct Fully
# Qualified Domain Name (FQDN) and remove the # at the beginning of the line.
#
$myhostname = "abc.def.ghi";

1;  # ensure a defined return
```

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! I recommend [edit]ing this answer to expand it with specific details about how to do this. (See also [How do I write a good answer?](/help/how-to-answer) for general advice about what sorts of answers are considered most valuable on AskUbuntu.)

Comment: Sorry about that, I expanded the answer ;)